# Not able to read the external assembly after project referenced in .net core project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to install and configure Autofac on my Asp.Net Core project. I am referencing a project called CustomerOrder.Data in my Asp.Net Core project called CustomerOrder.Web. I am able to see the the project referenced successfully as well as can access the namespace using the using keyword. Although one of the class names in the namespace turn red. For eg. the namespace
using CustomerOrder.Data.Infrastructure;  the data in the namespace is read. Hence its not able to identify the interface and classes that I am referencing in my web project. Here is the code

**Project.Json file in CustomerOrder.Data project**

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "CustomerOrder.Model": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions": "1.1.0",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.1"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"

    }
  }
}
```

**For e.g DBFactory class in CustomerOrder.Data project**

```
namespace CustomerOrder.Data.Infrastructure
{
    public class DbFactory : Disposable, IDbFactory
    {
        CustomerOrderEntities _dbContext;
        private DbContextOptions<CustomerOrderEntities> _options;

        public CustomerOrderEntities Init()
        {
            _options = new DbContextOptions<CustomerOrderEntities>();
            return _dbContext ?? (_dbContext = new CustomerOrderEntities(_options));
        }

        protected override void DisposeCore()
        {
            _dbContext?.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs file in CustomerOrder.Web project**

```
public class Startup
{  
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddMvc();

            // Create the container builder.
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            // Register dependencies, populate the services from
            // the collection, and build the container. If you want
            // to dispose of the container at the end of the app,
            // be sure to keep a reference to it as a property or field.

           
            builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>();
            builder.RegisterType<DbFactory>().As<IDbFactory>();
            builder.RegisterType<CustomerRepository>().As<ICustomerRepository>();
            builder.RegisterType<ProductRepository>().As<ICustomerRepository>();
            builder.RegisterType<OrderRepository>().As<IOrderRepository>();

            builder.Populate(services);
            this.ApplicationContainer = builder.Build();

            // Create the IServiceProvider based on the container.
            return new AutofacServiceProvider(this.ApplicationContainer);

        }
}
```

**Project.Json file in CustomerOrder.Web project**

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.AngularServices": "1.0.0-beta-000019",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection": "4.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational": "1.1.0",
    "CustomerOrder.Data": "1.0.0-*",
    "CustomerOrder.Model": "1.0.0-*",
    "CustomerOrder.Service": "1.0.0-*"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.6": {
      "imports": [
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "appsettings.json",
      "ClientApp/dist",
      "node_modules",
      "Views",
      "web.config",
      "wwwroot"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [
      "npm install",
      "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.vendor.js --env.prod",
      "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --env.prod"
    ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  },

  "tooling": {
    "defaultNamespace": "CustomerOrder.Web"
  }
}
```

For some reason the project cannot understand UnitOfWork,IUnitOfWork,DbFactory,IDbFactory etc

```
            builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>();
            builder.RegisterType<DbFactory>().As<IDbFactory>();
            builder.RegisterType<CustomerRepository>().As<ICustomerRepository>();
            builder.RegisterType<ProductRepository>().As<ICustomerRepository>();
            builder.RegisterType<OrderRepository>().As<IOrderRepository>();
```

There seems to be some issue with the core version. Has anybody faced this before ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem. Resharper was the culprit. I disabled resharper and everything works fine now.